# Make grid over an image using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have an image of 4000px by 3000px. I want to display this image on an html page and allow users to select coordinates over this image.

Actually I have to replicate from this: 
https://www.botb.com/CompetitionPlay.aspx?SiteID=1&region=GB&cid=2ca08b9b-4717-474c-b5ec-1e6a40df6d54&play=1

(Please register and see this element. Its free to sign up)

Actually I want to display this 4000x3000px picture in 700x500px div size but the user should be able to select coordinates in the picture relative to its actual size i.e 4000x3000px.

The problem with simple approach of scaling the pixels is that the user is only able to select coordinates from downscaled pixels. I want the user to able to select a coordinate from 4000*3000 possibilities

How can I fix a large dimensions image into that size and make magnify tool just like the one in the above? Is it possible in using html5 canvas?

If you can share any jquery plugin for this then I will be very grateful.

[image]

Comment: I am not going to register... use screenshots or try to explain better

Comment: See this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lk56k1tkp6pm5v/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2023.40.34.png?dl=0

Comment: Why not just embed the image on your question, the upload tool is already there Jezz. I just did it for you, It's not that hard.

Comment: The problem is that image size is 4000x3000 pixels so if I embed it then the image will not fit in the screen.

Comment: @faizi you can still click it to make it larger.

Comment: With a jQuery click event you can capture the x and y pixel position, then use that to calculate the position on the original (full sized) picture.    See if you can then overlay a div using position:absolute on the new div and embed it with the portion of the big image. That's where I would start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Image at 25% size:**

[image]

**Image with magnified section (magnified section is 100% size)**

[image]

Here's code to magnify the image when the user holds the mouse down over their desired magnification point.

The code uses a second overlaying canvas to present a portion of the magnified (full-sized) image.

**Example code and a Demo:**

This starting example uses a fixed size magnification viewport, but you can adjust to let the user use mousedown+mouseup to define a variable sized viewport.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var magifier=document.getElementById("magnifier");
var mctx=magnifier.getContext("2d");

var $magnifier=$('#magnifier');
var mw=100;
var mh=100;
var downscale=0.25;
var upscale=1/downscale;
var iw,ih;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/soccer.jpg";
function start(){
  magnify();
  iw=img.width;
  ih=img.height;
  cw=canvas.width=iw*downscale;
  ch=canvas.height=ih*downscale;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,cw,ch);
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas,#magnifier").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
}

function magnify(x,y){
  if(!x){$magnifier.css({left:-999}); return;};
  $magnifier.css({left:x-mw/2,top:y-mh/2});
  mctx.clearRect(0,0,mw,mh);
  mctx.drawImage(img,-(x)*upscale+mw/2,-(y)*upscale+mh/2);
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  magnify(x,y);
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  magnify();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#container{position:relative;}
#canvas{position:absolute;border:1px solid red;}
#magnifier{position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Hold mouse down for magnified view.</h4>
<div id=container>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <canvas id="magnifier" width=100 height=100></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You have done half of the part but now the main thing is that I want get the coordinates of the center of the magnified part and that coordinates should be related to original image size (4000x3000pixels)

Comment: @faizi You're welcome! **User selected viewbox:** To let the user select the viewport size, just record the mouse positions on mousedown and mouseup. Those 2 points define the top-left and bottom-left of your viewport. You can use the algorithms in my answer to scale the magnification of the user-selected viewbox. **Scaling related to the original size:** The code already does that! To adjust the small vs magnified sizes you can just change the `downscale` and `upscale` variables to something other than 25%. Now it's your turn to do the last bit of coding. :-) Good luck with your project.

Comment: @faizi **Regarding coordinate relation ship between small and magnified images** When the user does mouse down at `[x,y]` on the small image the user is selecting `[x*upscale,y*upscale]` on the magnified image (magnified image == the full 4000x3000px image).

Comment: The problem with your approach is that the user is only able to select coordinates from downscaled pixels. I want the user to able to select a coordinate from 4000*3000 possibilities.

Comment: As long as you keep track of the scaling factor you can present the user with the viewport at any scaled size.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this, you can use this to calculate the ratio to the original size too, just do the multiplication.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("box");
element.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  show(x, y);
}

function show(x, y) {
  coords.innerHTML = "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

```css
#box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: crosshair;
  
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/150/');
}
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
Coords <span id="coords">(X,Y)</span>
<div id="box"></div>
```